# How to trigger event when echart title is double clicked

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am trying to make it possible for the user to change an echarts title by double clicking it. The main issue I am having is on triggering the event.

I noticed on the documentation that they don't have an Instance for the Title component, so I would like to know if trigerring that event its even possible.

[Appendix: Component and Chart Instances](https://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/doc-en.html#Appendix-Component-and-Chart-Instances)

This exemple show several ways of catching events on the chart but none of them include the chart title.

[Event example](https://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/event.html#)

Having this exemple in mind, what I am trying to do would be something like:

```
myChart.on(ecConfig.EVENT.DBLCLICK.TITLE , eConsole);
```

Any suggestions on triggering this event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. As long as you have referenced your chart instance, you will be able to take any supported event that occured inside your chart component.

You have to enable `title.triggerEvent` by setting it to `true` (default is `false`). This will allow the title to fire events.

Then in your external methods, reference the chart instance and listen to its events with the `.on(eventName, function(params))`. The `params` object will contain the `componentType` string, which will tell you the name of the targeted component. All you have to do is a proper check on it!

Copy/paste this code to try it on the [official online editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html):

```
option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Click me',
    triggerEvent: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
    type: 'line'
  }]
};

myChart.on('dblclick', params => {
  if (params.componentType === 'title') {
    console.log('title is double-clicked!')
  }
})
```

And when you double-click the title, it will log this message in the console:

```
title is double-clicked!
```

Since there's the `componentType` check, it will only fire on title click.

To see more about possible event types and handling, please take a look at [this chapter](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Events%20and%20Actions%20in%20ECharts) in the documentation.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure if this is possible, because this is a really oddly specific and (at least for the devs) unusefull. Your best bet would be to detect a click on the surrounding div and to get the position of that click back. Then you would be able to determine of the click was within the right area and thus make a `click on title` event.

For getting the position I would give this a look: [Position of click within div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855336/position-of-click-within-div)

Hope this helps at all.